# md5decrypter API

Tags: php, api, md5

So, there's this website (http://md5decrypter.co.uk) which, given an md5 hash, will attempt to return the original string.

Is there an API or has someone made a PHP class to work with it? I can't find one...

Before, you ask, let me assure you that I have no malicious intent.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ha, *let me assure you*. Classic.

Comment: MD5-"Decryptors" compares input strings with rainbow tables. Just create such a table and compare your string against the pre-calculated md5-hashes. However, trying to decrypt hashes makes you slighly suspicous ...

Comment: @KingCrunch I always wanted something like this. :D (My current nick supports the reasons) Thanks Mihir-Singh

Comment: I'm slightly unfamiliar with rainbow tables... If I 'made" one, I would have all hashes that md5decryptor? I'm asking for this specific site because I have found that they have the largest database.

Comment: @ChasingDeath welcome... But in all honesty guys, I have no malicious intent...

Comment: I do. :D I just wanted to find some passwords from an age-old database. Now, it seems like those passwords aren't MD5 crypted at all. :(

Comment: @KingCrunch With today's computing power, rainbow tables are outdated. They take up way too much space, and cracking passwords can be done quite fast on Amazon's clouds or similar.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Space is not expensive and with power you can evaluate multiple (partial) tables at once. I don't think, they are that useless. Slightly depends on wether you already have some tables, or not. If you need to create them first, then it's maybe really more useful to omit it.

Comment: @KingCrunch but at the same time, by "piggy-backing" off of md5decryptor, I would save myself space and processing power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even so the guy from md5decryptor is nice, he won't make his asset accessible to you via HTTP only because you're asking. As anybody else you can use the publicly available webinterface which requires a captcha - which says everything.

Or in short: No there ain't no PHP API out there.

However, why don't you run your own? It's rather trivial:

```
$decryptors = array('Google', 'Gromweb');

foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
    echo "$hash";
    foreach($decryptors as $decrytor)
    {
        if (NULL !== ($plain = MD5Decryptor::plain($hash, $decrytor))) {
            echo " - found: $plain ($decrytor)";
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
fcf1eed8596699624167416a1e7e122e - found: octopus (Google)
bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb - found: passw0rd (Google)
d0763edaa9d9bd2a9516280e9044d885 - found: monkey (Google)
dfd8c10c1b9b58c8bf102225ae3be9eb - found: 12081977 (Google)
ede6b50e7b5826fe48fc1f0fe772c48f - found: 1q2w3e4r5t6y (Google)
```

Those you're not able to directly look-up, you can paste at that site manually. Keep in mind if more folks think like you, more and more sites will go down (most of them are already).

```
abstract class MD5Decryptor
{
    abstract public function probe($hash);

    public static function plain($hash, $class = NULL)
    {
        if ($class === NULL) {
            $class = get_called_class();
        } else {
            $class = sprintf('MD5Decryptor%s', $class);
        }
        $decryptor = new $class();

        if (count($hash) > 1) {
            foreach ($hash as &$one) {
                $one = $decryptor->probe($one);
            }
        } else {
            $hash = $decryptor->probe($hash);
        }
        return $hash;
    }

    public function dictionaryAttack($hash, array $wordlist)
    {
        $hash = strtolower($hash);
        foreach ($wordlist as $word) {
            if (md5($word) === $hash)
                return $word;
        }
    }
}

abstract class MD5DecryptorWeb extends MD5Decryptor
{
    protected $url;

    public function getWordlist($hash)
    {
        $list = FALSE;
        $url = sprintf($this->url, $hash);
        if ($response = file_get_contents($url)) {
            $list[$response] = 1;
            $list += array_flip(preg_split('/\s+/', $response));
            $list += array_flip(preg_split('/(?:\s|\.)+/', $response));
            $list = array_keys($list);
        }
        return $list;
    }

    public function probe($hash)
    {
        $hash = strtolower($hash);
        return $this->dictionaryAttack($hash, $this->getWordlist($hash));
    }
}

class MD5DecryptorGoogle extends MD5DecryptorWeb
{
    protected $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%s';

}

class MD5DecryptorGromweb extends MD5DecryptorWeb
{
    protected $url = 'http://md5.gromweb.com/query/%s';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I know what you mean about him making it available for me just because I ask... Its just that [he had one](http://forum.hashkiller.com/index.php?topic=7352.0) two or three months ago, but it seems to have completely vanished....

Comment: And, I can't enter them manually because its part of an app that I'm writing...

Comment: @MihirSingh: Obviously that one ain't online any longer. And even that site wouldn't have given you all hashes plain, so in any case you have a leftover, so keep that apart and store for later manual cracking. or feed it to hashcat with rules etc, works pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be the case... :(

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 5 hours"... Well, see you then...

Comment: @hakre... Welcome. Quick question... Does this only work with Google and Gromweb? Or can I keep expanding it to get the most hashes cracked?

Comment: That's meant to be extended actually. As long as you keep the base class, this should play well.

Comment: @hakre... Ok thanks... And how easy is it to extend? Would I just have to do 
class MD5DecryptorService extends MD5DecryptorWeb
{
    protected $url = 'http://service.com/query/%s'
}?

Comment: It depends on the service for which you would like to integrate into the API.

Comment: Well, yes, but I meant do I just have to add the class and add the URL for the query? Or do I have to add it, or implement the class, else where?

Comment: As long as the class extends like the two others (google and Gromweb), it's equally easy: Just change the URL and the classname.

Comment: Hakre, when you are back online, could you address [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254482/catching-failed-http-request-in-php/) with the script?

Answer (score 1):

[BozoCrack](https://github.com/juuso/BozoCrack) is a dead simple ruby script that uses google as a rainbowtable and is frighteningly good at cracking unsalted MD5 passwords. Looking at the code it shouldn't be too hard to migrate it to PHP.

PS: everybody who uses unsalted MD5 as password hashing algorithm should have his passwords cracked, one for one ... don't use md5, [use bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)!

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your own:

```
<?php 
//From file or some John the ripper piped input
$wordlist=file('some_word_list.lst');

foreach ($wordlist as $word){
    $sql="INSERT INTO table (plain_word,hashed_word)values('$word','".md5($word)."')";
    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: I realize that, but I am limited by space and power. In addition, md5decryptor already has so many hashes... I couldn't think of or find so many words....