# Send and Retrieve data for Md5 Decryptor

Tags: php, parsing, encryption, md5

Im currently working on a network tools website and got stuck at the md5 decrypter, 
I want to send the input from my website to
http://md5decryption.com/
and then retrieve it.

is there anyway to do that?
thankyou

Comment: md5 has be broken(US govt has declared it) so I suggest you better switch to SHA1 or SHA2

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181616/md5decrypter-api

Comment: The problem is my client is insisting on md5, he said it's a must tool.

Comment: Does your client actually believe that md5 can be decrypted? Or does he realise that these decryptor sites aren't actually decrypting, but simply looking for a clash against a database?

Comment: @Marten : If it's really impossible i think i will use iframe instead

Comment: @Mark : He actually knew that, and still want it.

Comment: http://www.md5online.org/md5-api.html Actually provides an API for you, though check the requirements for premium usage

Comment: You rite, i'll check it.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

MD5 is neither a decrypter nor an encrypter it is a **HASH** algorithm. However, it's not a secure hash algorithm, if you want to use hash go with SHA3 which is a subset of *KECCAK*. If you need to use symmetric encryption this is totally different story. 
I advise you to read more about crypto primitives then start using the right ones.